# customizing nestedlist title, sencha touch 2 PR4

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-theming

The title and the back button are displayed inline while navigating the nestedlist, is it possible to display the title below the back button ?

Even though there are no child items in nested list, the nested list navigates and shows a blank screen. Could some one suggest how to avoid the blank screen when no child items are present ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to just add your own CSS to customize the title position of the title in NestedList.

As for a blank screen; I'm not sure what else could display when you have specified no items?